# Test whether stdout has been written to

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a script that prints in a loop.  I want the loop to print differently the first time from all other times (i.e., it should print differently if anything has been printed at all).  I am thinking a simple way would be to check whether anything has been printed yet (i.e., stdout has been written to).  Is there any way to determine that?

I know I could also write to a variable and test whether it's empty, but I'd like to avoid a variable if I can.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a variable? It will make your code more readable and maintainable.  What's the perceived cost?

Comment: Why not just test a loop counter? I know you say **I'd like to avoid a variable**, but why? The `redirect to a tmpfile` is a fine solution, but you are adding a whole lot more than a variable there... A simple `declare -i cnt; while [your loop]; do #stuff; if [ cnt -eq 0 ]; then printf "a"; else printf "b"; fi; ((cnt++)); done` is a lot shorter and avoids the tmpfile which adds IO time and overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will do what you need. If you `echo` something between `# THE SCRIPT ITSELF` and `# END`, `THE FOLLOWING DATA HAS BEEN WRITTEN TO STDOUT` will be printed `STDOUT HAS NOT BEEN TOUCHED` else...

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly TMP=$(mktemp /tmp/test_XXXXXX)

exec 3<> "$TMP"   # open tmp file as fd 3
exec 4>&1         # save current value of stdout as fd 4
exec >&3          # redirect stdout to fd 3 (tmp file)

# THE SCRIPT ITSELF

echo Hello World

# END

exec >&4          # restore save stdout
exec 3>&-         # close tmp file

TMP_SIZE=$(stat -f %z "$TMP")
if [ $TMP_SIZE -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "THE FOLLOWING DATA HAS BEEN WRITTEN TO STDOUT"
    echo
    cat "$TMP"
else
    echo "STDOUT HAS NOT BEEN TOUCHED"
fi

rm "$TMP"
```

So, output of the script as is:

```
THE FOLLOWING DATA HAS BEEN WRITTEN TO STDOUT

Hello World
```

and if you remove the `echo Hello World` line:

```
STDOUT HAS NOT BEEN TOUCHED
```

And if you really want to test that while running the script itself, you can do that, too :-)

```
#!/bin/bash

#FIRST ELSE
function echo_fl() {
    TMP_SIZE=$(stat -f %z "$TMP")
    if [ $TMP_SIZE -gt 0 ]; then
        echo $2
    else
        echo $1
    fi  
}

TMP=$(mktemp /tmp/test_XXXXXX)

exec 3 "$TMP"   # open tmp file as fd 3
exec 4>&1         # save current value of stdout as fd 4
exec >&3          # redirect stdout to fd 3 (tmp file)

# THE SCRIPT ITSELF

for f in fst snd trd; do
    echo_fl "$(echo $f | tr a-z A-Z)" "$f"
done

# END

exec >&4          # restore save stdout
exec 3>&-         # close tmp file

TMP_SIZE=$(stat -f %z "$TMP")
if [ $TMP_SIZE -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "THE FOLLOWING DATA HAS BEEN WRITTEN TO STDOUT"
    echo
    cat "$TMP"
else
    echo "STDOUT HAS NOT BEEN TOUCHED"
fi

rm "$TMP"
```

output is:

```
THE FOLLOWING DATA HAS BEEN WRITTEN TO STDOUT

FST
snd
trd
```

as you can see: Only the first line (`FST`) has caps on. That's what the `echo_fl` function does for you: If it's the first line of output, if echoes the first argument, if it's not it echoes the second argument :-)

Comment: This still creates `TMP` as a variable but it is pretty cool .. I may be able to get around it, though.  I think using a variable for what I'm trying to do is much easier.

Comment: yeah, it still creates variable `TMP`, but it also works if the output is done by some other program. Say if you put a `cat /etc/fstab` before the `for f in fst snd trd...` loop, `fst` will be printed with caps off! What's the problem with the variables?

Comment: By the way: `TMP` is more a constant than a variable. I marked it (edit) as `readonly` now.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do here, but if your script is printing to stdout, you could simply pipe it to perl:

```
yourcommand | perl -pe 'if ($. == 1) { print "First line is: $_" }'
```

It all depends on what kind of changes you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `-f` option with `%z`. The line `TMP_SIZE=$(stat -f %z "$TMP")` produces a long string that fails the test in `if [ $TMP_SIZE -gt 0 ]`.